# nasm error: label or instruction expected at the start of line

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

Hello I am very new to assembly(just started today) and ran into this problem when doing exactly what is said in this tutorial. I made an asm file with this text:

```
org 0x100 
start:
mov bx, [a]
mov ax, [val]
mov cx, 8
sub sp, 8
call search
ret

search:
mov di, sp
go:
    cmp [bx], ax
    jz detected
    continue:
        add bx, 2
        dec cx
        jnz go
        ret
detected:
    add di, 2
    shl word[bx], 2
    mov dx, [bx]
    mov [di], dx
    jmp continue



a dw 1, 2, 1, 4, 1, 6, 7 , 8
val dw 1
```

I get this error

```
laber.asm:1: error: label or instruction expected at the start of line
```

I am wondering if this is a bad tutorial or am I typing something wrong. also I would like to know what it means by "label or instruction".

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to show the command you used to assemble, and what OS you are on, and what output format you want. Due to the `org 0x100` I assume you want a DOS `.com` file. Now, your `nasm` might not default to that format, so you should try something like `nasm -f bin -o laber.com laber.asm`.

The error `label or instruction expected` isn't a terribly good message, and basically means nasm didn't recognize the `org` and tells you to use a label (something followed by a colon) or an instruction (I hope you know what those are ;)). Of course you could also use other things, such as a valid directive, but nasm doesn't tell you that.

Comment: The `org` directive is valid only in `-f bin` output format (and some exotic ones). Consider the possibility that it's also a bad tutorial. What's it supposed to do???

Answer (score 0):

You need to insert

```
section .text
```

at the top of your file.